# Excluding a project in an sbt multi project from being published (sbt-gpg)

Tags: scala, sbt

The latest version 0.8 of the [sbt-pgp plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp) introduces a new task `publish-signed` to push the products for example to the Sonatype OSS repository.

Now I had a multi project with an aggregate that was *not* to be published:

```
lazy val root: Project = Project(
  id        = "root",
  base      = file("."),
  aggregate = Seq(foo, bar, baz),
  settings  = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    publishLocal  := (),
    publish       := ()
  )
)
```

Now the `publish := ()` is *ignored* when using `publish-signed`. I already added:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.PgpKeys._
publishSigned := ()
```

This is no effect, the plugin still publishes the aggregate leading to a rejection by Sonatype (because it's empty, has no license info etc.)

**How do I exclude a project from being published using `publish-signed`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
lazy val root: Project = Project(
  id        = "root",
  base      = file("."),
  aggregate = Seq(foo, bar, baz),
  settings  = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    packagedArtifacts := Map.empty           // prevent publishing anything!
  )
)
```