# Prevent sbt from publishing an automatically aggregated root project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt multi project build with two projects `core` and `mac`. I don't have a root project which aggregates them. Unfortunately [sbt does create one automatically](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#default-root-project).

How can I prevent this dummy aggregate project from being published? I get something like `"default-6a1ca6"` apart from `core` and `mac` when I run `sbt publish-local`.

I am looking for something like

```
autoRoot := false
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `packagedArtifacts in file(".") := Map.empty`

With the latest SBT **0.13.1** and the following two files (and no other files inside the project):

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val core = project

lazy val mac = project
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

...executing `sbt publish-local` gives:

```
$ sbt publish-local
...
[info] Set current project to root-0__multi (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/0__multi/)
...
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/mac_2.10.pom
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/mac_2.10.jar
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/mac_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/mac_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info]  published root-0__multi_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/root-0__multi_2.10.pom
[info]  published root-0__multi_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/root-0__multi_2.10.jar
[info]  published root-0__multi_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/root-0__multi_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published root-0__multi_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/root-0__multi_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/core_2.10.pom
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/core_2.10.jar
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/core_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/core_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 4, 2014 1:38:28 AM
```

It means that by default all there projects are published.

When you however add the setting `packagedArtifacts in file(".") := Map.empty` to set `packagedArtifacts` for the current (root) project:

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val core = project

lazy val mac = project

packagedArtifacts in file(".") := Map.empty
```

...executing `sbt publish-local` gives:

```
$ sbt publish-local
...
[info] Set current project to root-0__multi (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/0__multi/)
...
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/root-0__multi_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/core_2.10.pom
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/core_2.10.jar
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/core_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published core_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/core_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/core/core_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/mac_2.10.pom
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/mac_2.10.jar
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/mac_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published mac_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/mac_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/mac/mac_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 4, 2014 1:39:34 AM
```

No current (root) project is published.

Answer (score 5):

For sbt 1.x you can also use

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
    aggregate(core, mac).
    settings(
        skip in publish := true
    )
```

See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3136

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735434/excluding-a-project-in-an-sbt-multi-project-from-being-published-sbt-gpg#18737767) is a work around: Create an explicit root project and disable publishing for it. I wish there was a simpler way, though.

Comment: You seem to be using pre-**0.13** release (as the name is `default-...` and should be the name of the main directory), don't you? What about `packagedArtifacts in file(".") := Map.empty`? It worked fine with SBT **0.13.2-M1**.

Comment: I use the latest stable, 0.13.1

Comment: Weird. Somehow the outputs from your runs and mine are different yet I tested SBT 0.13.1 and 0.13.2-M1 on two different OSes - Windows 7 and Mac OS X.